# Display overlay image in gallery variable

Tags: php, html, variables

I am struggling to find a way to add a layer variable dependent in a gallery.

```
if ($pricesold == 'upcoming') { ?>
           <div id="ManagerSpecial" style="z-index: 50; position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px;"><img alt="" src='https://test.co.uk/testpng.png' /></div>  }
```

The code below is from the single item view gallery and I want to display the overlay if $pricesold == 'upcoming'. The image is a png transparent image with a special offer I want to overlay if it has been marked with the variable "upcoming". I am having issues displaying the image in the same div!

```
<div id="slider" class="flexslider">

                            <ul class="slides cardeal_slide">
                                <?php
                                if ($autoshowroom_images = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'images')) {
                                    foreach ($autoshowroom_images[0] as $image) { ?>
                                        <li data-src="<?php echo esc_url(wp_get_attachment_url($image)); ?>">
                                            <a><img src="<?php echo esc_url(wp_get_attachment_url($image)); ?>"
                                                    alt="<?php echo esc_attr(get_the_title()); ?>"/></a>
                                        </li>
                                    <?php }
                                }
                                ?>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
```

Comment: Have you made the parent element (the one that `ManagerSpecial` is in) `position:relative`?

Comment: Also - although the code you use on the server to produce the HTML is PHP, this is not a PHP question.  You should really provide the final HTML as given to the browser, as it's a CSS problem

Comment: Ok will try that... and no, I used: position: absolute

Comment: In order for an element to be `absolute` positioned, it needs something to be `relative` to

Comment: Thank you for your feedback. Will try that now